# Google Maps JavaScript API : Dynamically style KML Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am making this interactive map using Google Maps API and I need your help on something.

First here is the example I'm working on : http://it-zone.ma/map/

A KML Polygon is loaded over Africa for it to be highlightable. I need to change the fillColor of the polygon when mouse is over it. In Google Maps API documentation, there is a chapter on Dynamically Styling Data Layers and another one on KML Layers but I can't seem to find any way to Dynamically Style KML Data Layers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't dynamically style KmlLayers.  You can use a [data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), a [FusionTables layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer), or a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=VoterDistricts_address.xml)